# How do I launch the "Manage another account" page from the "User Accounts" section in the control panel from a C# application

Tags: c#, user-accounts, process.start, controlpanel

How do I launch the "Manage another account" page from the "User Accounts" section in the control panel from a C# application?

I can currently launch the "User Accounts" app by using the command:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control.exe", "nusrmgr.cpl");

but I would like to avoid having to click on the "manage another account" link withing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use to get the users:

```
Win + R > control userpasswords2

Start > Search > netplwiz
```

**Update:**

You can also call it with the following commands but i can't find how to call the '**Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts\Manage Accounts**' directly other then the previously stated commands.

```
User Accounts = control /name Microsoft.UserAccounts

User Account Control Settings = UserAccountControlSettings
```

Sources:

[The Definitive Windows 7 Commands Guide](http://www.webtlk.com/the-definitive-windows-7-commands-guide/)

[Start | Run Commands for Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7:](http://ss64.com/nt/run.html)

[A List of Run Commands for Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5966-run-commands-windows-7-a.html)

Comment: This wasnt the exact window that is displayed by the control panel, but nevertheless... "netplwiz" command did the trick! thanks!